# How do I make data retrieval faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm developing an application that has 5 major tables where most reads are from and 4 other tables where data is being inserted. I'll provide details of 2 tables and the specific columns that are involved in this particular data retrieval.

Table 1: SystemsTable -- 2.2k+ rows

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| Serial1    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Serial2    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ModelNum   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ...        | ....         | ..   | 0   |         |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Index - ID & ModelNum. No Foreign Keys

Table 2: DetailTable -- 42k+ rows

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id1        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| Id2        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| Id3        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| Serial     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ...        | ....         | ..   | 0   |         |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Index - ID1, ID2, ID3. No Foreign Keys

I've written a JOIN query to pick Serials from Table 1 based on the modelNum and compare the Serials to Serial in DetailTable with an OR operator.

```
Select b.* from SystemsTable AS a 
INNER JOIN DetailTable AS b 
   ON (b.Serial LIKE concat('%',a.Serial1,'%')  OR 
       b.Serial LIKE concat('%',a.Serial2,'%'))  
WHERE a.modelNum = '1234';
```

I ran this query in MySQL Workbench. It's taking 31-32 seconds to retrieve 11.1k rows.

UPDATE:

```
 Select b.* from SystemsTable AS a 
    INNER JOIN DetailTable AS b 
       ON (b.Serial = a.Serial1  OR 
           b.Serial = a.Serial2)  
    WHERE a.modelNum = '1234';
```

When I replaced wildcards with '=', it's still taking 16s. Any suggestion on improving?

Comment: We will need information about indexes, table type, foreign keys, ...

Comment: ... and the EXPLAIN.

Comment: The only way to speed up `LIKE %x%` queries is to use a full-text index.

Comment: Your `ON` clause makes it effectively impossible to leverage any indexes in `DetailTable`, so it will have to scan it sequentially.  It may even have to scan it multiple times, which is bad.

Comment: Why do you need wildcards in the serial matching, instead of using an exact match?

Comment: What sort of retrieval time do you see if you change `select b.*` to `select count(*)` ?

Comment: To speed up `LIKE '%x%'` consider splitting it into two columns `LIKE 'x%'` and `LIKE 'y%'`, where `y` is the reversal of `x`. Takes more space, but uses ordinary indexes to speed things up. You can use a trigger to maintain the reversed column if you wish.

Comment: (So in your case you'd have four LIKEs, two for each of your current LIKEs, but they may be faster than the current timings. Try it and find out!)

Comment: @Michael & Strawberry - added more details now.

Comment: @Barmar - The Serial in DetailTable are being entered by users and hence not clean. That's why I've used wildcards.

Comment: @Mark - There's no change. It takes same time when I tried count(*)

Comment: @halfer How does that help if the searched string can be in the middle? It won't match at either end.

Comment: @halfer - Do you mean like this? `b.Serial LIKE concat('%',a.Serial1) OR b.Serial LIKE concat(a.Serial1, '%')`

Comment: @Vick He means `b.Serial LIKE CONCAT(a.Serial, '%') OR REVERSE(b.Serial) LIKE CONCAT(a.reverseSerial, '%')`

Comment: @RBarryYoung - In this case, what other option do I have?

Comment: Please post sample data for serial1 and serial2.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying! I'll work on Full-text search or other ways listed here and in the other post.

Comment: @Barmar , Hi. I removed the wildcards and replaced with =
It still takes 16s. Any suggestions to improve?

Comment: @Barmar: the idea of this technique, I believe, is to convert all `LIKE` comparisons so they do not start with a wildcard. Since everything prior to the wild-card benefits from a general column index, the two `LIKE` statements (with one the reverse of the other) is thought to be faster than a `LIKE` beginning with a wildcard, which does not use a standard index at all. I've not tried it, mind you - saw it here on Stack Overflow as an answer.

Comment: I'd be minded to store the reversed string rather than calculated it on the fly, however - I imagine `REVERSE()` might also have a speed penalty (though of course it is worth a try).

Comment: @Vick Make sure you have an index on the `Serial` field.

Comment: @halfer The suggestion to use a reversed field is useful when your original query is `LIKE %foo`. It doesn't help with `LIKE %foo%`, because it's not anchored to either end.

Comment: @Barmar: but doesn't doing it twice (once reversed) result in anchoring it at each end separately?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! Yes, the speed improved by 50% taking 8s now.

Comment: @halfer Suppose the field contains `xxxFOOyyy`, and you want to search for `FOO`. Anchoring at either end will prevent that. It doesn't match `FOO%` and the reversed field doesn't match `OOF%`.

Comment: No, it is _not_ a dup of that other query!  Your trigger finger is too fast.

Comment: Start another question, and I can spell out how a couple of added indexes, plus `UNION` can probably make the query faster.